# How to remove a string part not the Special Characters?

Tags: android

I know there's a lot of Answers in Google Search but it doesn't exactly fit from what I need.

I'm trying to get rid of "VIP" String part while using setText.

```
TextView removeTextPart = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.spinner_item_txt); String vip = "VIP";
        if (config.contains("VIP")) { //config is a external file in my assets folder which contains a filename "VIP - SOMETHING" 
            String vip = vip.replaceAll("VIP", "");
            removeTextPart.setText(vip+config);
        }
```

I'm expecting that when it reads the VIP String Part in my assets file it will remove the String just like "VIP - Something" String will be Replaced/removed from this " - Something".

Sorry for my Bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your replaceAll  function does but I think you should change

`String vip = replaceAll("VIP", "");`

to

```
String vip = string.replace("VIP", "");
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot to remove the All in replace my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to replace some part of string from original string is :

```
removeTextPart.setText(originalString.replace("VIP", " "));
```

replace method will return a string, so you can directly print it or also save in another temporary string.